# Confusion on adding list of orders into database using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

i am making a restaurant ordering system, all is going good except im getting confused at this part. Adding orders made by the customer to the database.

i have tables by the name `Order` and `OrderDetails` which have the following properties

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public **Customer** CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderedDateOn { get; set; }
    public string OrderDateFor { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string? DetailRequest { get; set; }
    public string? DetailReply { get; set; }
    public int ItemCount { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the order table

```
public class OrderDetails
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Order OrderID { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Item { get; set; }
    public int AmountOfItem { get; set; }
}
```

so how do i go about register the order made from the user.
do i first send the order to be registered, add the items along side the order ID to the `OrderDetails` table?
i am genuinely confused as to how the order will be registered.

Comment: Why `CustomerID` is `Customer` not a `Guid` (or `int`/`long`)? Why `Item` is a list?

Comment: yes, its Customer.. i edited it last minute.. and the List<Item> is the list of items the customer chose when ordering.

Comment: It does not make sense to me TBH. What is `AmountOfItem` then. Which Item since you have collection? Why  `Customer` is called `CustomerID`?

Comment: As for the question - EF is capable of creating multiple objects. You just add the root object to the corresponding `DbSet` and call save. The only thing to be aware is that if you are saving existing entity (customer) which is not tracked by EF - it will be created again (see this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Changing Foreign Keys and Navigations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes).

In your case it looks like `CustomerID` and `OrderID` should be guids and
and later you should have a navigation property:

```
public Customer Customer { get; set; }
```

Here's an example from the linked article:

> ```
> public class BlogAssets
> {
>    public int Id { get; set; } // Primary key
>    public byte[] Banner { get; set; }
>
>    public int? BlogId { get; set; } // Foreign key
>    public Blog Blog { get; set; } // Reference navigation
> }
> ```

Comment: Okay, so when adding the order, do i add it to the orderdetails table or the Order table

Comment: @Danny: you should have an `ICollection<OrderDetail> Details` property on your `Order`; create the new `Order`, then create all new `OrderDetail` objects and add them to `Details`, then store the newly created `Order` including it's details - just one call to `.SaveChanges()` and you're done!